# Borel's result on transcendence measure

Tags: math-history, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

In "Sur la nature arithmétique du nombre e" (Comptes rendus de l'Académie des Sciences 128 (1899), 596-9) Borel presented his result on transcendence measure for e. This can be restated as follows:

*For any positive $\varepsilon$ and for any polynomial $P \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with degree n satisfying $|P(e)| < \varepsilon$, there exist $M = M(n) >0, k = k(n) > 0$ such that
$$H \geq M\left(\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon}\right)^{\frac{k}{\ln \ln \frac{1}{\varepsilon}}},$$ where H denotes the height of P.*

I wonder, how he derived this bound? It may be obvious, but I can't figure it out.

I know that there exist much better results, but this seems to be a simple consequence of Hermite's theorem.

In addition, this proposition should be equivalent with following assertion:

*For any positive integer n, there are only  finitely many polynomials $P \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with degree n and height H satisfying $|P(e)|< H^{-c \ln \ln H}$ for some $c=c(n) > 0$.*

How can this equivalence be shown?